# ExtJS 6 specialkey event does not recoznize TAB key

Tags: tree, grid, extjs6

I am using the grid cell edit plugin for a tree grid. The specialkey listener does not seem to want to work when TAB is pressed. Enter and the arrow keys are ok. Any ideas?

Fiddle is here: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/14pk

Answer (score 0):

I've tryed your fiddle on EDGE,CHROME and FF and it works, pressing tab the alert show number 9 (number of tab key)

On which browser are you testing the program?

Comment: OK, that's really odd.  Using FF 44.  Just tried it on Chrome and it works fine....Tried again on FF and no dice.  Tried with cleared cache.  Still nothing.

Comment: really strange, i tested it also with ff last version